# By pass simple captcha

Tags: captcha

Currently, I have service have simple captcha (in image). Anyone know code java, php or node use to by pass it?

If you know any service by pass it please suggest me. [image]

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a CAPTCHA that it cannot be bypassed by robots? Surely it would be against the TOS to do that, too.

Comment: Yes. As I know. Now we have some AI can READ and UNDERSTAND as person. We have any ML by pass it (only simple catch as above)?